# Building NSMutableArray from NSMutableDictionary resulting in NSException

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, xcode, nsmutablearray

I am a newbie in iOS development. I was trying to put the results of an NSMutableArray into an NSMutableString but this is resulting in an NSException.
Here is my code:

```
NSMutableArray *oldtableData = .......this is where I recieve card data;
NSError *error;
NSMutableData *tableDataUpdated = [[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:oldtableData
                                                                       options:0
                                                                         error:&error] copy];
NSMutableDictionary *cardDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:tableDataUpdated options:0 error:NULL];
```

For converting the cardDictionary into a NSMutableArray, I am using this piece of code (which is giving me an NSException)

```
NSMutableArray *type = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray *last4Digits = [NSMutableArray array];
[cardDictionary enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
    [type addObject:[obj valueForKeyPath:@"type"]];
    [last4Digits addObject:[obj valueForKeyPath:@"last4Digits"]];
}];
```

But If I exclude the above code and try NSLog with this piece of code

```
NSLog(@"JSON: %@",cardDictionary);
```

Console will give a proper json result; something like this:

```
JSON: (
    {
    cardPciId = "###########";
    fingerPrint = ###########;
    last4Digits = 4321;
    type = Mastercard;
},
    {
    cardPciId = "###########";
    fingerPrint = ###########;
    last4Digits = 1234;
    type = Visa;
}
)
```

I am trying to convert this into two Arrays, one with all the "type"s and another one with all "last4Digits". But this is what I get

```
Uncaught exception: -[__NSCFArray enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:]:
unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff7060badf0
```

I tried to hover through StackOverFlow to find a solution but none of them seem to be working. :(

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `cardDictionary` is actually an `NSArray` instance containing the dictionaries. So, you should iterate through the array, and get `type` and `last4Digits` from each dictionary using [`objectForKey`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdictionary/1414347-objectforkey) instead of `valueForKeyPath`:

```
NSArray *cardDictionaries = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:tableDataUpdated options:0 error:NULL];

NSMutableArray *type = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray *last4Digits = [NSMutableArray array];

[cardDictionaries enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSDictionary *cardDictionary, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
  [type addObject:[cardDictionary objectForKey:@"type"]];
  [last4Digits addObject:[cardDictionary objectForKey:@"last4Digits"]];
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot going on here, but I want to point one thing out.

Table data is being serialized to JSON.

```
NSMutableData *tableDataUpdated = [[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:oldtableData
                                                                       options:0
                                                                         error:&error] copy];
```

Next, the data that was just serialized is de-serialized. It will always be the same array.

```
NSMutableDictionary *cardDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:tableDataUpdated options:0 error:NULL];
```

You will always get the same data back. You don't need to do the JSON step at all.